# Display alert message if button is pressed when no tableView cells selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView that has multiple selections enabled for the cells.

The TableViewController also contains a navigation bar with a BarButtonItem. When this button is selected another UITableViewController is opened.

I would like to add a parameter where if no selections are made to the UITableView than the `nextButton` will trigger an alert message saying that the user must select a row or more.

How can something like this be done?

Currently, in the didSelectRowAt method, I have a checkmark accessory enabled:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
}
```

Comment: You should keep `selected` state in the controller, not in the view itself.

Comment: you can store selected indexPath in array & on `nextButton` trigger check this array count and as per that show your dialog.

Comment: FYI, it is a generally a nicer user experience to simply prevent them from performing invalid operations, rather than showing an alert; Track the number of selected items and disable/enable the button as appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** To check if the `tableView` is empty, you can check if the `array`/`model` that you're using to fill the `tableView` is empty or not.

Let's suppose `arr` is the `array` we're using as `dataSource` for `tableView`,

```
var arr = [String]()
```

**2.** Next, for selected `indexPaths` in the `tableView`, you simply need to check if `indexPathsForSelectedRows` is empty or not.

If empty, then show `UIAlertController`, otherwise navigate to another `UITableViewController` as per your requirement.

Now, combining all the above conditions, the `@IBAction` for `nextButton` goes like,

```
@IBAction func onTapNextButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if arr.isEmpty || (tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows != nil && !tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows!.isEmpty) {
        //navigate to another UITableViewController
    } else {
        //Show Alert here...
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert..!!", message: "You must select atleast 1 row before proceeding.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }        
}
```

Comment: This solution works well, but what if the tableView is empty? The button should allow the user to navigate to the next ViewController

Comment: I appreciate your help, do you know how this can be done?

Comment: When a tableView is empty it does not have any sections. Sections are populated from JSON along with the records themselves.

Comment: The logic I am trying to figure out is if the tableView is empty, there are no rows to select therefore the alert should not come up and the user should be able to navigate to the next UITableViewController

Comment: @MalsLanster I've updated the answer as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable for storing indexpaths in the econtroller:

```
var selectedIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()
```

add selected indexPath into array whenever user selects a row:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
}
```

check if selected indexPaths is empty, then nothing is selected and you can present alert:

```
if selectedIndexPaths.isEmpty {
    //Present alert
}
```

Note that you didn't handle **Deselect** in the original question but the flow is similar.

Comment: Where should the if statement be called?

Comment: In the button action

Answer (score 0):

Define array that will store the selected `IndexPath`.

```
var arrSelectedIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()
```

Inside `cellForRowAt`, check your array contains current `IndexPath`. If yes then set `accessoryType` to `.checkmark` otherwise set to `.none`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello"

    if arrSelectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }

    return cell
}
```

Inside `didSelectRowAt`, first of all check your array contains the selected `IndexPath` or not. If it already selected then unselect it otherwise add selected `IndexPath` in array.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    if arrSelectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
        if let index = arrSelectedIndexPaths.firstIndex(of: indexPath) {
            arrSelectedIndexPaths.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
    else {
        arrSelectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
    }

    self.tblVW.reloadData() //This will reload entire TableView
    //OR
    self.tblVW.reloadRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: .none) // This will reload only selected Row
}
```

Your Button action code something like this.

```
@IBAction func YOUR_BUTTON_TRIGER_ACTION(_ sender: Any) {
    if arrSelectedIndexPaths.count <= 0 {
        //SHOW YOUR ALERT
    }
    else {
        //DO YOUR FURTHER TASK
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** don't write `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark` inside the `didSelectRowAt` because when you scroll your TABLEVIEW the selection was gone or misplaced.