# Writing a conditional statement for empty UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

The following function below is displaying an alert if no selections are made in UITableView.

But I do not want the alert to come up when the TableView has no records. How can this be done?

**Work so far:**

```
@IBAction func onTapNextButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    guard let selectedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows, !selectedIndexPaths.isEmpty else {
        //Show Alert here...
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert..!!", message: "You must select atleast 1 row before proceeding.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }

}
```

Comment: I think this has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57471793/display-alert-message-if-button-is-pressed-when-no-tableview-cells-selected). Kindly don't ask the same question twice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display alert message if button is pressed when no tableView cells selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57471793/display-alert-message-if-button-is-pressed-when-no-tableview-cells-selected)

Answer (score 0):

First check if the data source array is not empty, replace `dataSourceArray` with the real name

```
guard !dataSourceArray.isEmpty else { return } 
guard let selectedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows, 
      !selectedIndexPaths.isEmpty else { 
         let alert ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the object is that you're using as your data source (I'm assuming it's an array), check to see if that object (array) has zero elements.  So, for example, something like:

```
//tableViewData should be the name of the array you're using as your data source
if tableViewData.isEmpty {
    return 
}
```

That way if there are no rows, you exit the function, and it won't display the alert.

Answer (score 0):

```
// this is one way of checking if the tableView is empty

@IBAction func onTapNextButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if tableView.visibleCells.isEmpty {
        //table view is empty: do something
    } else {
        guard let selectedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows, !selectedIndexPaths.isEmpty else {
            //Show Alert here...
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert..!!", message: "You must select atleast 1 row before proceeding.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

***** Hope you like it *****